# Login page hit before OnStart() or OnResume() in .NET MAUI app

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, .net-maui

In my .NET MAUI app, I placed break points in `OnStart()` and `OnResume()` methods as well as the `OnAppearing()` method of my `LoginPage` which is the first item in the `Shell`.

I was surprised to see that I hit the `OnAppearing()` method of the `LoginPage`. Shouldn't I be hitting `OnStart()` if the app is starting for the first time or `OnResume()` if it's waking up?

I don't think this was the case in Xamarin Forms. Has something changed or there's a bug somewhere in my MAUI app?

P.S. This is important for a number of reasons but I was trying to handle my access and refresh tokens in `OnStart()` and `OnResume()` methods when I realized that I was not hitting them first which surprised me. I wanted to mention this to set the greater context of what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: where is `MainPage` being assigned?

Comment: `MainPage = new AppShell();` is what's in the constructor of `App.xaml.cs`.

Comment: the constructor runs before `OnStart`.  Moving that into `OnStart` will (probably) give you a more logical flow

Comment: I'm still confused though. I makes sense that the constructor is first. But then I expected either `OnStart()` or `OnResume()` to run depending on application state. I expected the `MainPage` to go next. Are you saying I need to set `MainPage = new AppShell()` in `OnStart()`?

Comment: I just ran a quick test and I get AppCtor, AppShellCtor, AppOnStart, MainPageCtor, MainPageOnAppearing

Comment: That makes sense. I’m not getting that

Comment: try using Console logging instead of breakpoints

Comment: Here's the order I got: App Ctor => AppShell Ctor => MainPage Ctor => MainPage OnAppearing => App OnStart. Not sure why in my case App OnStart is last. And this is a brand new clean-slate app I just created.

Comment: If this is the correct and standard order, where am I supposed to check if user should still be logged in e.g. things like if user's `access_token` is still valid, and call to refresh the token if expired, etc.

Comment: The App constructor is the new place to do setup in MAUI. It used to be OnStart for Xamarin.